# Obtener tipo de objeto en c#

Tags: c#, conversión-de-tipos, tipos, objeto

Supongan el siguiente código:

```
public struct Result
{
    public object objectResult
    public Type objectType;
}

Result resultado = CualquierFuncion();
```

La función `CualquierFuncion` sería algo así:

```
public Result CualquierFuncion()
{
   Result result;
   ...
   ...

   result.objectResult = myNewUnknowTypedObject;
   result.objectType = myNewUnknowTypedObject.GetType();
   return result
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer (o saber si es posible hacer y cómo) es algo como lo siguiente:

```
var xxx = (result.objectType) result.objectResult;
```

Sé que el typecast directo no va a funcionar, pero ¿es posible hacer esto de alguna forma que no sea comparando el valor de tipo guardado, con los diferentes tipos esperados?

Comment: Por definición si el tipo de datos no es conocido en tiempo de compilación el compilador no podrá inferirlo. Independiente del caso particular que estas preguntando, que intentas lograr?

Answer (score 1):

Usa `dynamic` y `Convert.ChangeType`

```
public class Test
{
    public void Saludo()
    {
        Console.Write("hola mundo");
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test prueba = new Test();
        Result objeto = new Result
        {
            objectResult = prueba,
            objectType = prueba.GetType()
        };

        dynamic miTest = Convert.ChangeType(objeto.objectResult, objeto.objectType);
        miTest.Saludo();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si definitivamente necesitas hacerlo de esa forma, podrías intentar con la siguiente línea de código:

```
var xxx = Convert.ChangeType(result.objectResult, Type.GetType(result.objectType));
```

Comment: Convert.ChangeType regresa un object, no podria llamar a sus metodos `xxx.miMetodo();`

Answer (score -1):

que tantas opciones de objetos podrías tener? lo q podrías hacer es hacer la consulta del tipo y de acuerdo a eso haces una conversión explicita

```
if (result.objectResult.GetType().Equals(typeof(AlgunaClaseQuePuedaSer)))
{
    var xxx = (AlgunaClaseQuePuedaSer) result.objectResult; 
}
else if (result.objectResult.GetType().Equals(typeof(OtraClaseQuePuedaSer)))
{
    var xxx = (OtraClaseQuePuedaSer) result.objectResult; 
}
```

Comment: Esto es exactamente lo que RaptoR **no** desea hacer

Comment: Exacto Carlos, como decia al formular la pregunta, se hacerlo de esta forma que dices, pero debido a que son varios tipos de datos diferentes, (son clases) me resulta muy complicado tener que repetir código, es por eso que necesito saber si hay alguna fórmula que funcione genericamente

Answer (score -2):

Yo lo haría de la siguiente manera:

```
public T CualquierFuncion<T>()
{
    T result;
    ...
    // Aquí 'result' debería llenarse 
    ...   

return result
}
```

De tal forma que `xxx` va a ser del tipo que sea retornado en la función

```
var xxx = CualquierFuncion();
```